# FOSUser did not encrypt Password Symfony 4

Tags: php, forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have FOSUser installed on a Symfony project. When I want to create a user, it works but the passwords are not encrypted in the database.

My User extends BaseUser as mentioned in the doc. My forms looks like this:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            $builder
            ->add('utilisateur', UserType::class)
        ;
    }
```

Then I submit a form:

```
$employe = new EmployeSpie();
        $form = $this->createForm(EmployeSpieType::class, $employe);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            $this->entityManager->persist($employe);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
            $this->addFlash('success', 'Employé crée avec succès');
            $this->redirectToRoute('admin.employes.index');
        }
```

I have no setter in my user class, Because I extend BaseUser, which have one.
Why when I submit a form to create a user is the password not encrypted?

Comment: Hello, did you have override the `app/config/security.yml` file

Comment: You are probably setting the `password` field, you need to set the `plainPassword` field instead. `password` field will be created from the encrypted version of that `plainPassword` field on persist and `plainPassword` will be emptied.